Is controlling for a time period (during which an economic crisis took place) controlling for fixed effects in a Cox extended model?
I'm using a Cox extended model to measure if job contract durations changed before or after labour reform A and B were passed. So the labour reform variable is time varying (0 if no reform, 1 if reform A passed, 2 if reform B passed). The catch is that the reforms were passed during an economic crisis. Would it make sense to say that I am controlling for fixed effects if I control for the time period of the economic crisis as a time varying variable? (ie. 0 before the crisis, 1 during the crisis, 2 after the crisis)?

you are estimating the effect of labour reform on the hazard of "failure" of job contracts, that is fail=job contract ends. The cox extended model as you correctly point out uses time-varying covariates of which your labour reform variable is. The extended cox, just like the ordinary cox, has only fixed effects. Random "frailty" variables can be used that act multiplicative on the hazard but these (I think) tend to be for clustered data where a person contributes more than one record (i.e. repeated events).
